# Meaning of "dimension" in "you can add it to celeries for extra flavor and "dimension"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> This tiny fruit (Lychee) has only six calories, you can add it to celeries for extra flavor and **dimension**.

I've seen it [here](https://ejoy-english.com/go/video/fruits-for-losing-weight/3520).

Comment: If you do a Google search for ["define dimension"](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+dimension), the second definition is almost identical to the sentence in your question: *an aspect or feature of a situation, problem, or thing.  "sun-dried tomatoes add a new dimension to this sauce"*

Comment: @stangdon could you please tell me some synonym.

Comment: It's a catch-all word used to lazily describe an addition of texture, taste, mouthfeel, or some other aspect of the food.

Answer (score 1):

Celery is very bland. Adding something to it would make it more flavourful.

The word is a bit tricky to use in this context. If it's used outside of 3D-geometry, *dimension* is an adjective used to describe making something better by adding to it.

In this case the author is using *dimensions* as a synonym for flavour. But it's a bit more complex than just flavour. You wouldn't say that salt and pepper gives something *dimension*, but maybe a spicy hot sauce, a tangy dip, or in this case, lychee would.

Other examples that I've seen are in music.

> The horn section gave the song more dimension.

Notice that it's singular since music and flavour don't have any dimension.

Comment: Is it a common word?